# Is this colinearity in display?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

I've fitted a regression model $$y_i = \beta_1x_i + \beta_2z_i.$$

Both $x_i$ and $z_i$ are known to have a positive effect on $y_i$. So, one would expect $\beta_1, \beta_2$ to both be positive.

However, in my case, $\beta_1 > 0$, and $\beta_2 < 0$.

Is this caused by colinearity?

$x_i$ and $z_i$ are kind of correlated. Here's a scatter-plot of them, the upwards trend is clear. [image]

So, my question is,

1. Would you agree that this is caused by colinearity, or do you have another idea? My thinking is, as you increase $z_i$, while you *should* see an increase in $y_i$, that is already caused by the simultaneous increase in $x_i$ (since they are correlated). So $\beta_2$ does not have to be positive, $\beta_1$ takes care of it.
2. Should I remove one of them from the regression equation?
3. Is there something else I can do?
4. Or just admit that my model's strength is going to be predictive accuracy, and not interpretation?

Comment: Why aren't you including a constant term in the model? Depending on the numbers you haven't shown on the axes, that could have a profound effect.

Comment: Results don't change by including $\alpha$.

Comment: Why don't you show us the output from the model including the constant term. Did you try adding an interaction to the model?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't really tell about collinearity from a display. The most common way to detect it is through VIFs, but I believe condition indexes are better (see the work of David Belsley and also [my dissertation](https://fordham.bepress.com/dissertations/AAI9926897/).

Second the fact that x and z are both known to have positive relationships with y, but that your results show one have a negative coefficient means that x and z are not orthogonal, but it does not necessarily mean they are collinear. When you have two variables on the right side, then the coefficients are estimates of the relationship after controlling for the other variable.

Third, whether you should remove one variable depends on your goals. Do you want to control for the other variable? Presumably, you do, or you would not have run this model.

Four, if you do find troublesome collinearity (using VIFs or condition indexes) there are a lot of things you can do. Perhaps the first choice would be ridge regression.

Five, if there is no troublesome collinearity your model may be very good at explanation, but you have to be clear what it explains.